# How to access webcam through opencv in bash?

Tags: opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, webcam-capture

When accessing webcam through python opencv, isOpened() returns False and no data is read. Does it has to do something with wsl?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/412), hardware access is not supported yet in WSL:

> Ben Hillis: Hardware access is another area we will be investigating in the future.

All hardware related CLI tools seem to fail (dmesg, lsblk, lsusb returns nothing, /dev is empty...) so it looks like this statement is still valid today. That explains why you cannot access your camera in OpenCV.