# How to fix "VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't find camera device" when opening a camera with Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to use Python OpenCV on a Windows Ubuntu terminal for a research project. However, when I try to open my camera to capture video I get `VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't find camera device`. How can I access my camera using OpenCV?

I tried to use `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` and I get `Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory`. The camera on my computer works when using the camera application.

I am using the following cv2 command to grab the video capture device.

```
import cv2

stream = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
```

Comment: I have same problem, I tried all posible ways, nothing found yet, continuosly 2 days I do research.

Comment: I ended up not using WSL and instead using the Command Line.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu for Windows is based on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).  WSL [does not provide hardware support](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/412) so it can't provide you with a driver for your camera.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387794/how-to-access-webcam-through-opencv-in-bash) as well.